# How to form Copper from Calcium in a supernova explosion?

Tags: supernova

What are the reasonable chain of reactions to form copper (63, 29) from ca(40, 20) during supernova explosion? And how it will happen? I do not understand the theory behind it. I thought that the reaction will end at Iron and now it does not make sense to me.

Comment: Could you give some context as to why you think there is a direct link between copper and calcium.

Answer (score 4):

Copper is not thought to be primarily *made* in a supernova. It is thought to be mainly produced by the [s-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-process) of slow neutron capture onto iron-peak nuclei that already exist inside a star. These reactions are *endothermic*.

The source of the neutrons is still somewhat debated, it could either be from the decay of $^{13}$C in relatively low-mass asymptotic giant branch stars or is more likely from the decay of $^{22}$Ne in more massive evolved stars (e.g. [Pignatari et al. 2010](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/710/2/1557/meta;jsessionid=F521A33E8AC70B164FD9E8D19FDF5ED8.c3)).

Below you can see a typical route for producing copper from $^{56}$Fe. The axes of the plot are neutron number on the x-axis and proton (atomic) number on the y-axis. Three neutron captures are followed by a beta decay, a neutron capture, a beta decay, then 3 more neutron captures followed by another beta decay to form $^{63}$Cu.

The net process is
$$ ^{56}{\rm Fe} + 7n \rightarrow \  ^{63}{\rm Cu} + 3e + 3\bar{\nu}_e$$

The copper is then *distributed* into the interstellar medium by a later supernova explosion in the same star.

If there are no "seed" iron-peak nuclei (e.g. in the first/second generation of stars), then copper can be inefficiently produced by explosive [r-process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-process) neutron capture during supernovae explosions. However, this would not contribute very much to the copper we see on the Earth.

[image: s-process network]